# Как заставить с++ код обработать данные из HTML формы?

Tags: php, html, c++

Вопрос: Возможно ли как то обработать данные полученные из html формы например из input с++ кодом если можно то как? Напишите или опишите пожалуйста самый простой пример. Если например есть html форма то можно ли её как то обработать не только средствами PHP или PHP должен передать эту информацию непосредственно программе на c++?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+cgi https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+cms

Comment: Нужно или из php вызывать библиотеку, написанную на C++, или писать веб-сервер целиком на крестах. Посмотрите похожие вопросы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/149380/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/308023/184217) (обязательно читайте там комментарии).

Answer (score 0):

Обработать можно с помощью регулярок. Подключаетесь к HTML странице и переносите её в док. или просто её качаете. И с помощью регулярных выржений мы можете обработать любой документ.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb982727.aspx#matchingandsearching

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: Страуструп - Программирование. Принципы  и практика с использованием С++ 2-ое издание (2016 г.) стр. 942

Comment: Похоже, ОП не на клиенте хочет парсить html, а написать веб-сервер на c++.

Comment: Можно попробовать пот это https://habrahabr.ru/post/174109/

Comment: http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/web/prg/cgi6/cgi.htm

Comment: SOAP абсолютно не в тему. CGI, в общем, близко, но где там c++?

Comment: Я же думал чувак прогуглит. http://blagin.ru/cgi-skript-na-c/

Comment: Для обширного понимая http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/cgi/cgidev.php